# Are there any ways to get a changing time every millisecond?

Tags: android, datetime

```
private long LagrangeCaculation(){
    Date date = new Date();
    long curMillis = date.getTime();
    long since = curMillis-birthMills;
    Long result = 0L;
    Long aloneResult;
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        if(size == "Big"){
            aloneResult = data[2][i];
        }else {
            aloneResult = data[1][i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                aloneResult *= (since - data[0][j]) / (data[0][i] - data[0][j]);
            }
        }
        result += aloneResult;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(size is another parameter i have)
Right now,I'm using this function(based on Lagrange polynomial) to get a changing time every millisecond by passing a System.currentMills.But it didn't work,it's not allowed to pass a changing time as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `System.currentTimeMillis` with the function itself instead of passing a parameter of `millis`. Thus, whenever `System.currentTimeMillis` is called in the for loop, the current system time will be returned. For example:

```
private long LagrangeCaculationForSmall(){
        Long result = 0L;
        Long aloneResult;
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            aloneResult = data[1][i];
            for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    aloneResult *= (System.currentTimeMillis() - data[0][j]) / (data[0][i] - data[0][j]);
                }
            }
            result += aloneResult;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

(Alternatively, if you want the ability to pass different time functions as a parameter, you could pass a lambda expression.)

Comment: Thanks for replying,but it still didn't work.I'll update my codes to which I'm using right now

Comment: @Ben Could you (a) try print statements to see what System.currentTimeMillis returns each time and (b) insert a Thread.sleep statementin the loop? There is a potential that the loop is running too quickly for change.

Comment: I found out that it's the value type that went wrong! Should do (double) in front of long that was used to do the division

Comment: @Ben Yeah, (in general) watch out for integer division vs. floating-point division and typecast where needed.